# CS50 Week5 Speller

Tags: linked-list, cs50

I am working on [CS50 week5 problem speller](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/5/speller/). I think I have some doubt about the load function. I mean, in my code, after hashing the word, I loaded the word to the head of the corresponding linked-list. And my code worked. However, I think I can also load the word to the end of the list. The problem is that I don't know how I can change my code to do that. Can you help me? Below is my code of the load funtion.

```
// Read through the dictionary word by word
while (fscanf(input, "%s\n", currWord) != EOF)
{
    // Create a temporary node to copy the word
    node *tempNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (tempNode == NULL)
    {
        fclose(input);
        return false;
    }
    strcpy(tempNode->word, currWord);

    // Get the key for that word
    int key = hash(currWord);

    // Load the word to the head of the corresponding linked-list
    if (table[key] == NULL)
    {
        tempNode->next = NULL;
        table[key] = tempNode;
    }
    else
    {
        tempNode->next = table[key];
        table[key] = tempNode;
    }

    // Count the number of loaded words
    wordCount++;
}

// Close the dictionary
fclose(input);
return true;
}
```

If you need more information, please tell me! THANKS!!!

Comment: Review the [Singly-Linked Lists short](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/shorts/singly_linked_lists/) starting at around 14:00. Doug describes the method to "tack on" to the end of the list......and why it isn't the best idea.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus well, I think I get it, thanks!